# Grouper with different frequencies

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, pandas-groupby

I am trying to group my data by date with the pandas class Grouper.
My data is weekly and I can easily group it monthly like this:

```
data.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq = 'M').sum()
```

I would like to also group it bimonthly or in semesters, however, these two are not part of the documented frequencies (see [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#offset-aliases)).

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: did you try something like this i.e 2W or 3M `df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key="Publish date", freq="1W")).sum()` [grouper reference](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html)

Comment: You can use `freq='2M'` for bimonthly. I am not clear on what "semester" mean. Do you mean school semester (Sep - Dec, Jan - Apr, May - Aug)?

Answer (score 1):

Toy example:

Say we have weekly data as below which we want to covert to Monthly freq and sum the values of px column:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date':pd.date_range('2020.05.01', periods=12, freq='W'),
    'px':np.arange(12)
})
df
```

**Input df**

```
    date        px
0   2020-05-03  0
1   2020-05-10  1
2   2020-05-17  2
3   2020-05-24  3
4   2020-05-31  4
5   2020-06-07  5
6   2020-06-14  6
7   2020-06-21  7
8   2020-06-28  8
9   2020-07-05  9
10  2020-07-12  10
11  2020-07-19  11
```

We can convert it to month freq in two ways.

**Using resample**

```
df.resample('M', on='date').sum()
```

**Using Grouper**

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='M')).sum()
```

**Output**

```
            px
date    
2020-05-31  10
2020-06-30  26
2020-07-31  30
```